# Json:Failure to load multiple sub dictionaries using

Tags: python, json, dictionary, load

I am trying to load a json (based on a python dictionary) into a tool, as demonstrated below. Everything goes well.The problem is that out of the appended sub dictionaries of the last key-value pair only the first ('phase:46,part 008') will be loaded in.
The other key value pairs are being ignored.
However, when the subdictionaries consist of two different key value pairs(eg. 'normal phases' and 'abnormal phases', each containing one key value pair), there is no such problem and both get loaded correctly. Does anybody have a suggestion why this could be the case?
The Json looks as follows:

```
{
    "nr": 135300,
    "first_age": 86,
    "heart_rate": "51",
    "metabolism": "Average & Assigned",
    "normal_phases": [
        {
            "phase": 46,
            "part": "008"
        },
        [
            {
                "phase": 45,
                "part": "053"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "phase": 567,
                "part": "007"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "phase": 591,
                "part": "446"
            }
        ]
    ]
},
```

To give you an idea, a code snippet to create the last dictionary (phase 591, part 446):

```
        else:
            
            dict6 = [{'phase': int(a[45]),
                      'part': (a[17])}]
            
            
            d['normal_phases'].append(dict6)
```

Comment: NB every sub dict is inside a list. So you should iterate over the "normal_phases" key and collect them all if needed. Can you share your attempt as well as the expected output?

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean assigning all the phase and part values to their respective key. e.g.: creating only one dictionary with 4 values per key instead of 4 separate dictionaries?

Comment: I am not sure of the expected output, since I do not know the proper Json construction the tool would accept for the 'normal phases' pairs. I have added a snippet of code for the last pair.

Comment: Ahh I am not sure what's the end requirement, but if the phaser and the part will always be read together, then yep, I meant storing all phase as a list and so would be corresponding phase.